# GEOTOOLS - Animations

Tags: geotools, animation

I am new to GeoTools and I have been reading some examples and  some tutorials.

I am currently implementing a Map where I need to have a sprite moving through coordinates. I found an example right [here][1]

[1]: http://svn.osgeo.org/geotools/tags/2.7.1/demo/example/src/main/java/org/geotools/demo/swing/FlyingSaucer.java [] but it's very old and some methods have changed specifically these ones:

```
public void onRenderingCompleted() {
    super.onRenderingCompleted();
    System.out.println("hi");
    spriteBackground = null;
    animationTimer.start();
}
```

This method has changed and doesn't allow me to @Override JMapPane method and it also now requires a parameter. I tried to replace it but it didn't work. Here is my replacement:

```
public void onRenderingCompleted() {
    super.onRenderingCompleted(null);
    spriteBackground = null;
    animationTimer.start();
}
```

There are other minor changes as well (MapContext is deprecated so I must use MapContent).

Could someone tell me how to replace those methods to make this tutorial work or post a link here with a recent example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is to change `onRenderingCompleted(...) to be:

```
@Override
  public void onRenderingCompleted(RenderingExecutorEvent event) {

    super.onRenderingCompleted(event);

    spriteBackground = null;
    animationTimer.start();

  }
```

But you should take the [FAQ answer](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/unsupported/swing/faq.html) into account and consider doing this properly with two (or more) buffers to save redrawing whole map each time.